# How to set page header starting from second page

Tags: asp.net-core, pdf-generation, pdfsharp, migradoc, pdfsharpcore

First page in Migradoc PDF file should not have page header.
All remaining pages should have same header.
I tried

> ```
>         var document = new Document { };
>         var Section = document.AddSection();
>         Section.PageSetup = document.DefaultPageSetup.Clone();
>         Section.PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = true;
>         Section.Headers.Primary.AddParagraph("Page header for all pages except first page");
>         Section.PageSetup.TopMargin = "1cm";
>         Section.PageSetup.HeaderDistance = 0;
>         for (int i = 1; i < 77; i++)
>             Section.AddParagraph("Line " + i);
> ```

But this adds empty space in top of first page:

[image]

If

```
    Section.PageSetup.TopMargin = "0cm";
```

Is used, header overlaps with contents:

[image]

How to add header starting from second page so that there is no empty space in start of first page ?

Negative SpaceBefore for first paragraph in page fixes the issue. Since this is ignored for first paragraph, it requires adding dummy zero-heigth paragraph before it.
DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter also requires duplicating footerfor first and remaining pages.

Should those hacks used?

Using .NET Core PdfSharp-Migradoc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Footer distance applies to all headers.
`SpaceBefore` seems like an approach for the first page. Yes, a dummy paragraph is required.
Maybe a dummy paragraph with a negative `SpaceAfter` can also be used - I did not try this.